# Why is gnome-disks using LUKS1?

Tags: partitioning, gnome, encryption, disk-utility

I noticed that the application called `gnome-disks` which is the disk manager in many distros under the gnome and other desktops, gives you the option to encrypt a partition with LUKS.

It only offers LUKS1, which was developed in 2004. Isn't there a newer version to that or something stronger, I doubt personally that something so old is still strong. Isn't there a LUKS2 for example or a software with stronger encryption of partitions?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/LUKS_docs/on-disk-format.pdf clearly states **2016**, so obviously the LUKS v1 spec receives updates.   "I doubt personally that something so old is still strong" plenty of cryptographical algorithms and techniques are *old*. RSA was published in 1977, so will you stop using it?

Comment: @muru yes but RSA has different key sizes and while the 1024 bit key size might have been good back in the 70's, by now a 4096 is suggested. I am not sure how the LUKS system handles key sizes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First good encryption is hard, and not something for us mere mortals to roll our selves. Linux Unifed Key Setup aka LUKS started as a way to standardize encryption key setup.

In [on-disk-format.pdf](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/LUKS_docs/on-disk-format.pdf) states "The LUKS design can be used with any cipher or cipher mode." So as needs have changed ciphers can be changed.

Use Something Stronger?

from cryptsetup wiki [FrequentlyAskedQuestions](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) - [Security Aspects](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#5-security-aspects).

> ```
> Passphrase entropy  Cost to break
> 50 bit              EUR/USD   600k
> 55 bit              EUR/USD    20M
> 60 bit              EUR/USD   600M
> 65 bit              EUR/USD    20B
> 70 bit              EUR/USD   600B
> 75 bit              EUR/USD    20T
> ```

Why not use LUKS2?

LUKS2 does not yet have a fixed API. See [release notes](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/docs/v2.0.0-RC0-ReleaseNotes) for Cryptsetup 2.0.0 RC0.

From the release notse:

> Release candidate with experimental features.
>
> This version introduces a new on-disk LUKS2 format.
>
> The legacy LUKS (referenced as LUKS1) will be fully supported
>   forever as well as a traditional and fully backward compatible format.
>
> NOTE: This version changes soname of libcryptsetup library and increases major version for all public symbols.
>   Most of the old functions are fully backward compatible, so onlyrecompilation of programs should be needed.
>
> Please note that authenticated disk encryption, noncryptographicdata integrity protection (dm-integrity), use of Argon2 >Password-Based Key Derivation Function and the LUKS2 on-disk format >itself are new features and can contain some bugs. Please do not use it without properly configured backup or in production systems.
>
> Until final 2.0 version is released, the new API calls or LUKS2 format could still change if a major problem is found.

Comment: Note that 2.0.0 is still a RC (release candidate). It's not a released version yet.

Comment: As of now, it appears [LUKS2](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/LUKS2-docs) is now stable? If so, this is technically an outdated answer. I also used gnome-disk-utility 3.36.1 with UDisks 2.8.4 (built against 2.8.4) and noticed the same issue.

Comment: As of cryptsetup v2.1.0 Luks2 is the default for new volumes. See [cryptsetup v2.1.0 release notes](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/docs/v2.1.0-ReleaseNotes). @JWF thank you for reminding my of this answer. If you would like to research and improve my answer simply submit an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/965621/edit) or your own answer. Other wise I will look into an update.